# Python tkinter create image

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a visualised card game. I want to make a system where tkinter would show me a picture but the picture name is made of to other variables. `tkinter` will let me add only one value but I want to add two walues.

```py
raam=Tk()
raam.title("joonistus")
tahvel=Canvas(raam, width=1900, height=1000, background="black")
tahvel.grid()

kaart=[["poti","ruutu","risti","ärtu"],["kaks","kolm","neli","viis","kuus","seitse","kaheksa","üheksa","kümme","poiss","emand","kuningas","äss"]]
#in the finished game I would have more of these pictures imported
poti kaks= PhotoImage(file="doesn't_matter.gif")

tahvel.create_image(20,950, anchor=SW, image=kaart[0][0], kaart[1][0])
```

I know that I can also use other libraries but I want to try make this game using only `tkinter`.
Thank you for your support!

Comment: can you please update you code so that it is working "out of the box"? (e.g. add imports, fix syntax errors etc)

Comment: do you want to get the image from combining multiple words that way getting a file name or do you want to combine multiple images into one, or use multiple images to create one bigger, like say you have 9 images that are derived from one images split into 9?

Comment: I want to get a file name my combining multiple words

Comment: So what is the filename exactly you expect from the example code in your question?